# How to see the number of segwit transactions in a block

Tags: segregated-witness

Now that segwit is active I am interested to know how many segwit transactions are in each block.

The Blockchain explorers I've looked at don't seem to be tracking this info.

Is there any service that would allow me to view the number of segwit transactions which are in each block.

Comment: [I’m interested](https://steemit.com/cryptocurrency/@anonymint/shocking-crisis-coming-to-cryptocurrency-in-sept) in charts of % of BTC (per block or other period) transacted in SegWit transactions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[segwit.party/charts](http://segwit.party/charts) has an overview of SegWit related statistcs. They show:

- Percentage of SegWit transactions per block
- Count of segwit transactions and total transactions
- Percentage of witness size of complete block
- Actual witness size and block size

Comment: Link appears to be broken

Comment: You can view percentage of segwit usage on 144 blocks average on: https://p2sh.info/dashboard/db/segwit-usage

Answer (score 7):

Look here under "Transactions (Segwit)" tab:

https://oxt.me/charts

And here's a page showing exactly what you're looking for:

http://segwit.5gbfree.com/countsegwit

Comment: http://segwit.5gbfree.com/countsegwit.html has a nice graph too

Answer (score 0):

There is new blockexplorer called [yogh.io](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/6vm0fg/yoghio_a_segregated_witness_explorer_and/) which specifically shows fields in segwit tx. You can ask them to add number of segwit tx in block, should be easy to do. Or fork their [github code](https://github.com/JornC/bitcoin-transaction-explorer) and make any changes you require